# How to ignore UserWarning in python

Tags: python

I am trying to restart my main.py file through another file (unlock.py) calling the redo function from (restart.py) which restarts main.py:

```
import time
import sys
import os

def redo(): 
    time.sleep(5)
    os.execv(sys.executable, 
            [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'main.py')] + sys.argv[1:])
```

However, I am getting a UserWarning error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216:
UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore
objects to clean up at shutdown   warnings.warn('resource_tracker:
There appear to be %d '
```

So I used this to try fix it but it did not work as the warning still appears:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately It's a bug(Python 3.8).I guess that's why you can't filter it

Python issue :https://bugs.python.org/issue38842

Comment: Thats unfortunate... is there absolutely no way around it?

Comment: if your'r running from console you can disable warnings "python -W ignore file_name.py"

Comment: try adding "import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")" in main.py